# Can someone explain how arrayJoin() function works in Clickhouse database?

Tags: database, clickhouse

I am a newbie to ClickHouse DB and the example provided in the documentation doesn't help in properly understanding the concept. Explanation with how [arrayjoin()](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/query_language/functions/array_join/) can be used with simple scenarios would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's consider the next scenarios:

1. when need to transform *Array* to a *relation* (set of rows)

```sql
/* get error */
SELECT 1
WHERE 1 IN ([1, 2]);

/* ok */
SELECT 1
WHERE 1 IN (SELECT arrayJoin([1, 2]));
```

```sql
/* get error */
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT [1, 2] a)
WHERE a = 2;

/* ok */
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT arrayJoin([1, 2]) a)
WHERE a = 2;
```

2. to unfold/flatten the rows

```sql
SELECT
    metric_id,
    metric_name,
    arrayJoin(metric_values) AS metric_value
FROM
( /* test data */
    SELECT
        1 AS metric_id,
        'name_1' AS metric_name,
        [1, 4, 55] AS metric_values
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        2 AS metric_id,
        'name_2' AS metric_name,
        [-7, 11] AS metric_values
)
/* result
┌─metric_id─┬─metric_name─┬─metric_value─┐
│         1 │ name_1      │            1 │
│         1 │ name_1      │            4 │
│         1 │ name_1      │           55 │
│         2 │ name_2      │           -7 │
│         2 │ name_2      │           11 │
└───────────┴─────────────┴──────────────┘
*/
```

```sql
/* produce Cartesian product */
SELECT
    arrayJoin([1, 2]) AS n,
    arrayJoin(['a', 'b']) AS ll,
    arrayJoin(['A', 'B']) AS ul
/* result
┌─n─┬─ll─┬─ul─┐
│ 1 │ a  │ A  │
│ 1 │ a  │ B  │
│ 1 │ b  │ A  │
│ 1 │ b  │ B  │
│ 2 │ a  │ A  │
│ 2 │ a  │ B  │
│ 2 │ b  │ A  │
│ 2 │ b  │ B  │
└───┴────┴────┘
*/
```

```sql
/* flatten the multidimension array */
SELECT arrayJoin(arrayJoin([[1, 2], [3, 4]])) AS d
/* result
┌─d─┐
│ 1 │
│ 2 │
│ 3 │
│ 4 │
└───┘
*/
```

---

When you need to chain arrays item by item instead of getting cartesian product consider using [ARRAY JOIN](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/select/array-join/):

```sql
/* cartesian product */

SELECT
    arrayJoin(arr1),
    arrayJoin(arr2)
FROM
(
    SELECT
        [1, 2] AS arr1,
        [11, 22] AS arr2
)

/*
┌─arrayJoin(arr1)─┬─arrayJoin(arr2)─┐
│               1 │              11 │
│               1 │              22 │
│               2 │              11 │
│               2 │              22 │
└─────────────────┴─────────────────┘
*/


/* connect array's item one by one */

SELECT a1, a2, arr1, arr2
FROM
(
    SELECT
        [1, 2] AS arr1,
        [11, 22] AS arr2
)
ARRAY JOIN arr1 as a1, arr2 as a2

/*
┌─a1─┬─a2─┬─arr1──┬─arr2────┐
│  1 │ 11 │ [1,2] │ [11,22] │
│  2 │ 22 │ [1,2] │ [11,22] │
└────┴────┴───────┴─────────┘
*/
```