# how to use array join in Clickhouse

Tags: clickhouse

I'm trying to split 2 arrays using arrayJoin()

my table:

```
create table test_array(
    col1 Array(INT),
    col2 Array(INT),
    col3 String
)
engine = TinyLog;
```

then i insert these values:

```
insert into test_array values ([1,2],[11,22],'Text');
insert into test_array values ([5,6],[55,66],'Text');
```

when i split the first array in col1 the result will be like this :

[image]

***but what i need is to split col1 and col2 and add them in the select.***

I tried this query but it didn't work.

```
select arrayJoin(col1)  ,arrayJoin(col2) ,col1 , col2 ,col3 from test_array;
```

[image]

how can i edit the query to remove the **highlighted rows** in the picture?

Thanks.

Comment: see for details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60519194/can-someone-explain-how-arrayjoin-function-works-in-clickhouse-database

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The serial calls of [arrayJoin](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/array-join/) produces the cartesian product, to avoid it use [ARRAY JOIN](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/select/array-join/):

```sql
SELECT
    c1,
    c2,
    col1,
    col2,
    col3
FROM test_array
ARRAY JOIN
    col1 AS c1,
    col2 AS c2

/*
┌─c1─┬─c2─┬─col1──┬─col2────┬─col3─┐
│  1 │ 11 │ [1,2] │ [11,22] │ Text │
│  2 │ 22 │ [1,2] │ [11,22] │ Text │
│  5 │ 55 │ [5,6] │ [55,66] │ Text │
│  6 │ 66 │ [5,6] │ [55,66] │ Text │
└────┴────┴───────┴─────────┴──────┘
*/
```

Comment: Thanks @vladimir

Comment: @alim np, I glad to help.

Answer (score 3):

one more way -- tuple()

```
SELECT
    untuple(arrayJoin(arrayZip(col1, col2))),
    col3
FROM test_array

┌─_ut_1─┬─_ut_2─┬─col3─┐
│     1 │    11 │ Text │
│     2 │    22 │ Text │
│     5 │    55 │ Text │
│     6 │    66 │ Text │
└───────┴───────┴──────┘
```

Comment: Thanks @Denny Crane